# Change thousands sign using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[Here](https://dreifurlen.ch/test/) I would like to replace in the draggable slider the "," sign used for the thousands into this sign " ' " (a quote mark).

I am currently using a plugin to render the table (from a JSON file) so I cannot alter the HTML.

I am able to change the sign, in fact on page load the sign seems correct, but as soon I drag the slider the separator changes to a comma again.

I saw that the data is rendered from the Plugin with a comma in the aria-valuetext="" attribute: `<div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-upper" data-handle="1" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuetext="2,290.00"><div class="noUi-tooltip">2,290.00</div></div>`

I tried using this code without any results:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var div = document.querySelectorAll('.noUi-tooltip');

    div.forEach(function(r) {
        var text = r.textContent;
        var output = text.replace(/[,|]/g, "'");
        r.innerHTML = output;
    });

}       
</script>
```

What am I writing wrong?

I am using WordPress and the wpdatatables plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to to use `console.log()` to see if `text` and `output` contain the desired values?

Comment: Some part of the plug-in is re-rendering the value it has stored when you drag the slider. You will likely need to modify the plug-in or find something in the plug-in settings (internationalization?) to do this trick for you.

Comment: I don't know how much you can control the slider but maybe a look at  https://refreshless.com/nouislider/number-formatting/ helps

Comment: Which is the plugin?

Comment: @trincot the plugin is wpdatatables

Comment: Are the data formatted that way in the JSON? If so, either have the provider of the data change the format, or alter the data after receiving it.

Comment: According to the documentation of [wpdatatables](https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/general/configuration/) you can configures the number format, including the thousands separator. If it doesn't offer a way to set your preferred separator, then I would strongly advise to abandon that route, and choose a different plugin.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No the data in JSON is formatted in this way: 2120

Comment: @KHansen what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the plugin you've used for your slider but perhaps you can try this for now:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
      var parentEl = document.getElementsByClassName('noUi-handle-upper');
      var childEl = parentEl.childNodes[0];
      childEl.innerHTML = childEl.innerHTML.replace(',', '\'');
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('noUi-handle-upper')[0], {
  attributes: true,
});
```

It's using `MutationObserver` which is not supported by older browsers. You can read more about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you modify the string just in the beginning (on load).
This is why the code works in the beginning but doesn't work later, because it runs once and then stops.
I don't know how to use WordPress or sliders, but I'd advise you to use an 'on value changed' command, so the text will change to whatever you want it to each time the slider's value is changed.

I will post this now but I'll review your code and will try to update this with more exact information later.